# Swagger 3.0 - ContentType not identified for form data parameters

Tags: java, spring, rest, annotations, swagger

I am using Swagger 3.0, While submitting post api with form parameters from swagger UI, the request are sent without

```
ContentType:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

And due to this, getting below exception.

I could see from GitHub, an issue related to this. But not sure, is it still open or fixed.

https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/3583

Swagger version :swagger-annotations-2.0.0-rc4 and rc3

Exception:

```
11-Feb-2018 10:14:50.637 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-7] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet [userRestApplicationJersey] in context with path [] threw exception 
[java.lang.IllegalStateException: The @FormParam is utilized when the content type of the request entity is not application/x-www-form-urlencoded] with root cause
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The @FormParam is utilized when the content type of the request entity is not application/x-www-form-urlencoded
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.inject.FormParamValueParamProvider$FormParamValueProvider.ensureValidRequest(FormParamValueParamProvider.java:131)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.inject.FormParamValueParamProvider$FormParamValueProvider.getForm(FormParamValueParamProvider.java:205)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.inject.FormParamValueParamProvider$FormParamValueProvider.apply(FormParamValueParamProvider.java:156)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.inject.FormParamValueParamProvider$FormParamValueProvider.apply(FormParamValueParamProvider.java:107)
```

Comment: There's no "Swagger 3.0" because Swagger is [not a single project](https://swagger.io/tools/). Do you mean Swagger UI 3.0? [OpenAPI 3.0](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/3.0.0.md)? Something else? Can you post the code you are using?

Comment: Its OpenAPI 3.o